# Pronterface will not connect to 3D printer

Tags: permissions, printing

When I click connect in `Pronterface` for it to connect to my 3D Printer (a `Rigidbot`) I get this error message:

```
stty: /dev/ttyACM0: Permission denied
[ERROR] Could not connect to /dev/ttyACM0 at baudrate 250000:
Serial error: could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyACM0'
[ERROR] Could not connect to /dev/ttyACM0 at baudrate 250000:
Serial error: could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

I have tried different baud rates but all come up with the same error message. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell XPS 13 9343 (Developer edition).

What else can I try to connect to the 3D Printer?